# Complex Loop through a complex SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, arrays, xml, loops, simplexml

I need to save some values from XML.

First step - I get the structure:

```
 $xml = $dom_xml->saveXML();
 $xml_ = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
 dd($xml_);
```

Here `TextFrame` has 8 arrays. Each of them has `PathPointType`, which has 
4 more arrays with 3 attributes each. And these attributes I need from each `TextFrame`.

[image]

I can get, for instance, `Anchor` value doing this:

```
$res = $xml_
        ->Spread
        ->TextFrame
        ->Properties
        ->PathGeometry
        ->GeometryPathType
        ->PathPointArray
        ->PathPointType
        ->attributes();
    dd($res['Anchor']);
```

(BTW: is there more prettier way to get it?)

But the question is - how is it possible to loop through all arrays and save values separately for each array?

I assume here has to be a multidimensional `foreach` loop in conjunction with `for` loop?

Or is better to achieve it using `DOMDocument`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks as though you are starting off with DOMDocument (as you are using `$dom_xml->saveXML()` to generate the XML), it may be easier to continue using it and it also has some easy features for getting the details your after.

Using `getElementsByTagName()` allows you to get a list of the elements with a specific tag name from a start point, so starting with `$dom_xml`, get all of the `<TextFrame>` elements.  Then `foreach()` over this list and using this element as a start point, use `getElementsByTagName("PathPointType")` to get the nested `<PathPointType>` elements.  At this point you can then use `getAttribute("Anchor")` for each of the attributes you need from the `<PathPointType>` elements...

```
$textFrames = $dom_xml->getElementsByTagName("TextFrame");

foreach ( $textFrames as $frame )   {
    $pathPointTypes = $frame->getElementsByTagName("PathPointType");
    foreach ( $pathPointTypes as $type )    {
        echo $type->getAttribute("Anchor").PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You can extend the code to build an array of frames and then the anchors within that.  This code also stores the anchor in an associative array so that if you add the other attributes, you can add them here (or remove it if you don't need another layer of detail)...

```
$frames =[];
foreach ( $textFrames as $frame )   {
    $anchors = [];
    $pathPointTypes = $frame->getElementsByTagName("PathPointType");
    foreach ( $pathPointTypes as $type )    {
        $anchors[] = ['Anchor' => $type->getAttribute("Anchor")];
    }
    $frames[] = $anchors;
}
```

Also if you have some way of identifying the frames, you could create an associative array at that level as well...

```
$frames[$frameID] = $anchors;
```

Comment: Well, this works. I've changed the code a little bit to get all of them in one array `$anchors[] = $type->getAttribute("Anchor").PHP_EOL;` Now I have to think over how to separate them according to Textframes.

Comment: not really.  I've just realized, from the other side thought, I don't need to. I mean I think I can use them without separating. Do not delete your edit, will try it tomorrow.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: I hope you don't mind me stealing all your code and posting an alternative answer. Every time I see someone recommend DOM for a simple task, I have an itch to show how SimpleXML would look; though, to be fair, DOM comes off fairly well, here, because `getElementsByTagName` is easier to grok than XPath.

Comment: @IMSoP, no problems.  As for 'recommending' DOM - I prefer SimpleXML, but as OP looks as though they are already using DOM I thought I would try and stick with that.  It seems to be difficult enough to get someone to use XML and not ask *how to convert it to an array*, so 1 API is probably easier.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to [the existing answer from Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54735455/157957), I thought I'd show how the same loops look with SimpleXML.

Firstly, note that you don't need to convert the XML to string and back if you want to switch between DOM and SimpleXML for any reason, you can use [simplexml_import_dom](http://php.net/simplexml_import_dom) which just swaps out the interface:

```
 $sxml = simplexml_import_dom($dom_xml);
```

Next we need our `TextFrame` elements; we could either step through the structure explicitly, as you had before:

```
$textFrames = $sxml->Spread->TextFrame;
```

Or we could use XPath to search for matching tag names within our current node (`.` is the current element, and `//` means "any descendant":

```
$textFrames = $sxml->xpath('.//TextFrame');
```

The first will give you a `SimpleXMLElement` object, and the second an array, but either way, you can use `foreach` to go through the matches.

This time we definitely want an XPath expression to get the `PathPointType` nodes, to avoid all the nested loops through levels we're not that interested in:

```
foreach ( $textFrames as $frame )   {
    $pathPointTypes = $frame->xpath('.//PathPointType');
    foreach ( $pathPointTypes as $type )    {
        echo $type['Anchor'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to call `$type->attributes()`; unless you're dealing with namespaces, all you need to get an attribute is `$node['AttributeName']`. Beware that attributes in SimpleXML are objects though, so you'll often want to force them to be strings with `(string)$node['AttributeName']`.

To take the final example, you might then have something like this:

```
$frames = [];
foreach ( $sxml->Spread->TextFrame as $frame )   {
    $anchors = [];
    $pathPointTypes = $frame->xpath('.//PathPointType');
    foreach ( $pathPointTypes as $type )    {
        $anchors[] = ['Anchor' => (string)$type['Anchor']];
    }
    $frames[] = $anchors;
}
```

Comment: Perfect explaining! Now I got some new experience with SimpleXML. Thank you too. I appriciate your help!